# Что использовать для написания бота

Tags: javascript, расширения

Подскажите что использовать или почитать что бы выполнить задание:

"Есть два сайта ( `site1.com` | `site2.com` ) мне нужно с сайта 1 считывать инфу которая приходит через WebSockets анализировать и на сайте 2 симулировать нажатие определенных кнопок"

В какую сторону смотреть? Расширение под Хром, юзерскрипты?

Comment: Попробуйте `phantomjs`.

Comment: @KostaB. Какой принцип работы?

Comment: @KostaB. И что если нужен графический интерфейс?

Comment: Это бот на `JS`. Для симуляции нажатий как раз подходит [Подробнее](https://habr.com/search/?q=phantomjs#h)

Comment: @KostaB. а трафик WS можно будет считать? Есть документация по phantomjs?

Comment: [Документация](http://lmgtfy.com/?q=phantomjs) |  [Подключение к WebSockets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27642875/how-to-monitor-websocket-communication-in-phantom-js)

Comment: @KostaB. Спасибо